# converting and sending a double amount in android studio

Tags: java

I would like to ask why when I am trying to send a double value from one activity to another, only the default value is showing which is 0.0 whenever I input a number to convert.
This is my java code in the main activity
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMkQm.png)

And this is the java code in the second activity
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ALl2k.png)

Comment: Don't post screenshots of your code, post the code instead! Also, post only relevant parts of the code, i.e. the part where you send and receive the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in your code:
In first activity the name is `convertedAmount` and in your second activity the name is `converted amount`. That is the reason you're getting the default value.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice it. I am still new to android studio